# Parse Complex Json String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to parse the following JSON string (not in control of the format, I know it's hideous).

```
    var json = '{"what.1.does":"anything", "nestedjsonstr":"{\"whatup\":\"nada\"}"}';
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

I'm getting `Error: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 43` which is where the first value of nestedjsonstr begins. Is there any elegant way to parse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you out. You replace the curly braces inside your string without the `"`, and remove the `\`.

```js
var json = '{"what.1.does":"anything", "nestedjsonstr":"{\"whatup\":\"nada\"}"}';

json = json.replace('\"{', '{').replace('}\"', '}').replace('\\"', '"');

obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is it safe enough to clear all the escape characters though (as that would clear it in the entire json string)?

Comment: Maybe try `json = json.replace('\"{', '{').replace('}\"', '}').replace('\\"', '"')`. I'll edit the answer